# Update Ubuntu Touch without using image streams (i.e. how to update without removing programs installed with apt-get)?

Tags: upgrade, updates, ubuntu-touch, phone, meizu-mx4

Is there a way to get the latest updates of Ubuntu Touch features without replacing the entire root directory with a new OTA image? I had some applications installed via terminal using apt-get, as well as a couple of scripts in my root directory, but after turning off Developer Mode and updating, they are wiped – entire root directory is replaced with an updated image. I tried "apt-get upgrade" before using System Settings->Updates, but it didn't update anything. I am not using my phone as a dedicated development device, but I am a power user. Is there (yet) an alternative way for me to receive updated features whilst still keeping my custom tweaks/installations? I don't mind if its a complicated or round-about way, as long as it works.

Will I have to custom-download new images, load them in a virtual-machine, use a script to copy over all my changes, then manually flash that to my Meizu MX4? If so where do I get the image and what virtual machine will work? Or is there a better/easier way?

Comment: I expect that the safest solution will not be by copying changes, but by saving the list of manually installed packages and just repeating this installation step after each image update. Theory speaking - I haven't yet tried it on a phone. - And manual edits to existing files are yet another story I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can't be done. What you should be doing instead is installing your custom apps in a chroot stored in your userdata partition, and leave the root partition alone. Doing otherwise compromises in fact you receiving official updates on your phone.